# Error whit JPA on update

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, netbeans-7

I have working with JPA on little desktop system. The problem is after the system updates a table 4 or 5 times correctly, the sixth time updates wrong, then the seventh time works well, until after 10 times it fails again once or twice more.

Details: Use JPA 2.0 with eclipselink and Netbeans 7.0.1. I'm using mysql.

I hope can you help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with relevant code & exceptions if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show more details of what are you trying to update and the database structure, but for my experience you should verify the values of the registers that you are trying to update. For example the datetimes most of the time should have this format **"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"** for work in *MySQL*. Another important point is the null values you have to concatenate to the *JPA* update statement only a **null**, and not a string with the character null, empty or a space. I think that is a type of value problem but show me more details and i will help you.